# Can't open a kerberos connection FROM web API hosted on IIS using app pool user

Tags: c#, api, iis, .net-core, kerberos

I wrote a web API in .net Core 3.1 which is hosted on an unmanaged APP POOL. What the API does is authenticate the client accessing it. The client is sending a JSON payload that has a query and a named database in it.

After retrieving the payload the API is supposed to open a connection to a remote database using the app pool's user credentials. I don't want the clients' credentials forwarded, I want the app pools credentials to be used. The connection to the database uses MIT-Kerberos as a client authentication method.

This is where it fails. All I get is the following stack trace:

2020-08-14 09:46:31.5417 COM.Core.ComLog Error User: Une erreur inattendue est survenue: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): [HY000]
[Native Code: 30155]
[ASEOLEDB]Could not load gssapi library.
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()

....

There's more but it is non-specific and does not list a cause. Furthermore there is no inner exception. I have also tried ODBC and I get the exact same message with either connection protocol.

I wrote a very basic console program that does the same thing but without controllers and the .net core middelware. When I run it using the same ID as the app_pool on the server the connection is successful.

The fact that the API is hosted on IIS seems to be causing the problem but I just can't seem to figure out why the API can't connect to the remote. Authentication is set to deny anonymous access and Windows authentication is set to true with Negotiate and NTLM in the providers of the app pool.

We've looked up all the PATH variable destinations for kerberos and made sure the 64 bit version libraries are accesible at every location. Still no go.

I am either too dumb to figure it out or dumbfounded by this issue. I hope someone out there has an idea of what could be happening. I haven't found anyything on the web except the generic kerberos installation guides. ugh.

Comment: Try to set the “Load User Profile” option in the Advanced Settings of the application pool to true.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twd8n.png
In my opinion, I suggest you use SQL Server authentication instead of windows authentication to connect the SQL database. 
https://www.connectionstrings.com/ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/

Comment: I started having the same connection issue locally whether hosted on IIS or not. After a lot of trial and error trying to configure the MIT-Kerberos client I gave up and re-installed the client. Which worked. So I pressed the server admin to do the same on the server. After trying a truckload of things he relented. And my connections on the server inside IIS or out were restored. It was the Kerberos client all along even though it appeared to work correctly granting the correct key and showing it in the list.

Comment: @AbrahamQian We were using SQL authentication but that requires sending a uid/pwd in the connection string unless you're on MSSQL. The entire point of this API is to remove using u/p when connecting to the backend from other apps which in some cases are fat clients (i.e. the user is the one initiating the connection). Since we don't want to grant access to the backend to the entirety of the users this API is the vehicle to accomplish this using an active directory service account on the app_pool which makes all the SQL requests on the caller's behalf and returns JSON messages to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this may that Load User Profile option in IIS AppPool advanced settings is set to "false". Try setting it to "true".
This way you may assure yourself that your application pool will use these credentials.